# Spring MVC - UnknownFormatConversionException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem with UknownFormatConversionException. Could anybody help me?
I am writing an order by a client in my application using Spring Web Flow.

Here is problem:

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ')'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2579)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2565)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.InMemoryCartRepository.delete(InMemoryCartRepository.java:40)
    at com.packt.webstore.service.impl.CartServiceImpl.delete(CartServiceImpl.java:34)
    at com.packt.webstore.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.saveOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

InMemoryCartRepository

```
@Repository
public class InMemoryCartRepository implements CartRepository{
    private Map<String, Cart> listOfCarts = new HashMap<String,Cart>();
    public void delete(String cartId) {
        if(!listOfCarts.keySet().contains(cartId)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Nie można usunąć koszyka. Koszyk o wskazanym id (%) nie istnieje." , cartId));
        }
        listOfCarts.remove(cartId);
    }
}
```

CartServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class CartServiceImpl implements CartService{

    @Autowired
    private CartRepository cartRepository;

public void delete(String cartId) {
        cartRepository.delete(cartId);

    }
}
```

OrderServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService{

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CartService cartService;
    public Long saveOrder(Order order) {
        Long orderId = orderRepository.saveOrder(order);
        cartService.delete(order.getCart().getCartId());
        return orderId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is thrown from your `String.format` : the format is not valid, a 's' is missing in `(%)`: it should be `(%s)` :

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Nie można usunąć koszyka. Koszyk o wskazanym id (%s) nie istnieje." , cartId));
```